# Distributive on myself

Tags: code-golf

### Background

We all know about distributivity, i.e. \$a(b+c) = ab + ac\$. This is a property on *2* different operations, namely addition and multiplication. But indeed, nothing can stop us from studying distributivity of 1 operation. In this challenge, you will be studying a kind of left-distributive operation.

### Task

Given a positive integer \$N\$. Consider an operation \$p \star q\$ where \$p, q\in\{0, 1,\dots, N-1\}\$, such that \$ p \star 1 \equiv p + 1 \pmod N\$ and \$p \star (q \star r) = (p \star q) \star (p \star r)\$. In essence, you are making an \$N\times N\$ table. For instance, if \$N = 4\$, a possible \$\star\$ is:

```
⋆ q 0 1 2 3
p-+---------
0 | 0 1 2 3
1 | 0 2 0 2 ←
2 | 0 3 0 3
3 | 0 0 0 0
      ↑
```

Note that the marked column satisfies \$ p \star 1 \equiv p + 1 \pmod N\$. In this challenge, we are interested in the marked *row*. It seems to be periodic, and the challenge is to find its period. The smallest positive period for a sequence \$a_0, \dots , a_{N-1}\$, is defined to be the smallest positive integer \$k\$, such that \$k\$ divides \$N\$, and \$a_i = a_{i + k}\$, for \$i=0..(N-k-1)\$.

However, there may be many possible \$\star\$'s for a given \$N\$, or there may be none. So you need to compute the (smallest positive) periods for all of them.

> Task: given a positive integer `N`, compute all the possible smallest positive periods of `1 ⋆ q`. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

### Details and clarifications

In the case `N = 4`, the given table turns out to be the only possible one, so you should output a list (or a set, etc.) consisting only of the number `2`. But for `N = 3`, no operation satisfies all the requirements, so you can output an empty list, or 0, or some falsy value.

The smallest positive period will always be between 1 and \$N\$, if the sequence `1 ⋆ q` (`0 <= q < N`) doesn't repeat at all, it is of period \$N\$.

`N` will range from 1 to \$2^{32}-1\$. So it is almost [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity). But note that a formula or recurrence relation of this is unknown.

### Test cases

```
In : N = 1
Out: [1]

In : N = 2
Out: [1]

In : N = 3
Out: []

In : N = 4
Out: [2]
```

Comment: @Arnauld Yeah, I originally planned to require the output each period seperated by spaces for each `N=1..1024`, seperated by newlines. Later I decided to take input, and enlarge the upper limit. Forgot to change the tag.

Comment: Do you have any test cases for `N>4`?

Comment: Shouldn't the output for `n=2` be `[1]`? The only possible operation has the table `0 1 \\ 0 0`, and `0 0` has period 1.

Comment: Such an operation can only exist when `N` is a power of 2.

Comment: @att Why can it only exist for `N` a power of 2?

Comment: @att whoops, yep

Comment: https://oeis.org/A098820

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 113 bytes

```python
N=input()
f=lambda p,q:f(f(p,q-1),-~p%N)if p*q else q
print([i for i in range(1,N)if N%i+f(1,i)<1]+[N])[:N&N-1<1]
```

*-2 bytes thanks to @Jakque*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHBbsMgDL3zFRZTV1hopPQYLfuEXHbMqiproLOUAgUq1st@PXPTtdqkcTG233t@YH9OH86uJ/2pd9uYAtp9wzmf2gatPyUhmWnG/vA@9ODVsTbCCIqrSqrVl1@0Eg34pyPoMWo4Mk/8JDoE4wIgoIXQ270WlZqR7QILQwnK52pTdO1GdnX72K4qSieayljSMUVoYMSYxI1bVVIy9gCveDiNfdIQ00DS84wfk3jwLiRwUcVzZEFBJhEXS49eU9vqvL2S5qoZnNdWEGwZlpK5cbh2FRC7vAHvdwV3Pst/FDIpZFK4P3f2XzOgk8scMGkRtA8CJRTA3yyXLJe70cWLq39p8xcCKt68cDVXLqsRv/Yjp28)

The short, recursive approach is slow since it repeats computation of many entries, so I've made an [iterative, memoized approach](https://tio.run/##bVPLbtswELzzKxYKWpMxY0QO0EMB9RN86dEVAsVa2UQtkibpqEbRb3eXlPUIHAICxJ3Z4XB3aS/hYPTLFf/g7tUHp/S@yLLsuimUDlxpew5cCNZiW/z9x1iNDTTcypP4zoCWasAWxXO/icthODsNpxm6ecrv8OcBP32WPUfvc7ld5uLLhs1CZG@bXJW9RYtOmZpPJjdfo4uBvi1T/AGw3iPsKo9@JMYTR15ezuLrKb4eBHyoXIDGmRbCAeHNhGDaJ6f2hwCVrqEz7jeYs4OuusDZSmiU8wGO2ISYoFNM4zs6sJX3VH2o3sw7JrW2UhpqVe2Nro7pwHRPuomkT5RFX6fGUDIQ1VV6jwSvZS4Jnwp3K89alFDcNstcxjKWIyeqnCaVlwRPEjOZU5Jp@LCNVhI7kcPMlZr0cgmbmVwoGh7I0BigEocPozDr7lZRW62LAzk0VlxpSBkL6IMnM9v146O6O/JbHIcH@Kna87EKSM2qCUysfq6Zaq2h/hkv/cUzJ6EjMeNXVlkkWGP32ielaFMbi5oTbeEWgplj3aMSKHs1EMf/2NhbPus@KHSk0JHCaDjdo797t@qcCsgdWseVgCVkv3QmWLfaHY2Prj5N68ujZFb8yCTquljAoq9ufNl89rzF9T8) which is much faster (quadratic in `N`) and can compute up to `N=4096` within 60 seconds on TIO.

## How it Works

The algorithm assumes that \$\star\$ is unique, if it exists (proof below). It uses recursion, setting

\$p\star q=\begin{cases}
q, &p=0 \\
p+1 \mod n, &q=1 \\
(p \star (q-1 \mod n))\star (p+1 \mod n), &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\$

The first case (\$p=0\$) is Lemma 1 in the uniqueness proof: \$0\star q=q\$.

The second case (\$q=1\$) is given.

The third case has a simple proof despite its complex self (assuming addition and subtraction are mod \$N\$:

\begin{align*}
&p \star q\\
=&p \star ((q-1)+1) \\
=&p \star ((q-1)\star 1) \\
=&(p \star (q-1))\star(p\star 1) \\
=&(p \star (q-1))\star(p+1)
\end{align*}

This is enough to determine the unique \$\star\$ (The proof shows that the third case will not recurse indefinitely).

The period is the minimum \$i\$ such that \$1\star (i+1) = 1\star 1 = 2\$. If this \$i\$ doesn't divide \$N\$, then it is not a period.

#### Ungolfed code:

```python
# f(p,q,N) = p⋆q
def f(p,q,N):
    if p==0:
        return q
    if q==1:
        return (p+1)%N
    return f(f(p,(q-1)%N,N),(p+1)%N, N)

def period(N):
    if any(f(p,f(q,r,N),N) != f(f(p,q,N),f(p,r,N),N) for p in range(N) for q in range(N) for r in range(N)):
        # The f does not exist
        return []
    for i in range(1, N):
        # period is i if f(1,i+1)=f(1,1)=2
        if f(1,i+1,N) == 2:
            # might not be divisible, in which case it is not the period
            if N%i:
                return [N]
            return [i]
```

This could be sped up immensely by memoization utilizing \$ a \star 2 = a \star (1 \star 1) = (a\star 1)\star (a\star 1) = (a+1)\star(a+1) \$ and \$1 \star a = (1\star (a-1))\star 2\$.

## Proof of Uniqueness of \$\star\$

For this section, we assume all addition/subtraction is mod \$N\$.

**Lemma 1**: For all \$a\$, \$0 \star a = a\$

*Proof*: Induction

Base case: \$a=1\$. Given since \$0\star 1=1\$.

Step: Assume this lemma holds for \$a=k\$. Then \begin{align*}
&0 \star (k + 1)\\
=&  0\star (k\star 1) \\
=& (0\star k)\star (0\star 1) \\
=& k \star 1 \\
=& k+1,
\end{align*}
so this holds for \$a=k+1\$. Since this addition is mod \$N\$, this will "wrap around" back to \$0\$, so it applies for \$a=0\$ too, not just \$a\geq 1\$

**Theorem**: If an operation \$\star\$ is valid for a given \$N\$, then it the unique \$\star\$ that is valid for that \$N\$.

*Proof:* We use strong induction to show that, for all \$0\leq a,b\leq N-1\$, \$a\star b\$ is uniquely determined by \$N\$. In addition, for each \$a\$ and \$b\$ in the same set, either (1) \$a\star b=0\$ or (2) \$a<a\star b<N\$

1. Base case: \$a\star b\$ is uniquely determined and equal to \$0\$ for \$a=N-1\$ and for all \$b\$.

   We prove this base case with induction too.

   1. Base case: \$b=1\$. We are given \$a\star 1=a+1\$, so \$(N-1)\star 1=0\$, uniquely determined.
   2. Step: Given \$(N-1)\star b=0\$ for \$b=k\$, then
      \begin{align*}
            &(N-1)\star (b+1)\\
            =&(N-1)\star (b\star 1)\\
            =&((N-1)\star b)\star((N-1)\star 1)\\
            =&0\star0 \\
            =&0,
          \end{align*}
      where we use Lemma 1 to show \$0\star 0=0\$,
      so \$(N-1)\star b\$ is uniquely determiend to be \$0\$.
2. Assume \$a\star b\$ is uniquely determined and either (1) or (2) hold for all \$k<a\leq N-1\$ and for all \$b\$. Then for \$a=k\$, we will show \$a\star b\$ is uniquely determined and either (1) or (2) hold for all \$b\$, again with induction.

   1. Base case: \$k\star b\$ is uniquely determined and either (1) or (2) hold for \$b=1\$. This is trivial since \$k\star 1=k+1>k\$, so \$k\star 1\$ is unique and (2) holds
   2. Step: Assume \$k\star b\$ is uniquely determined and either (1) or (2) hold for \$b=j\$. Then:
      \begin{align*}
            &k\star (b+1)\\
            =&k\star (b\star 1)\\
            =&(k\star b)\star(k\star 1)\\
            =&(k\star b)\star(k+1)
          \end{align*}
      If (1) holds, then \$k\star b=0\$, so \$k\star(b+1)=k+1>k\$ by Lemma 1. Thus \$k\star(b+1)\$ is uniquely determined and satisfies (2).

      If (2) holds, then \$k<k\star b\leq N-1\$,so by the outer inductive assumption, \$k\star(b+1)=(k\star b)\star (k+1)\$ is uniquely determined and either (1) or (2) holds for it.

      In either case, \$k\star(b+1)\$ is uniquely determined and either (1) or (2) hold for it, completing the inductive step.

Comment: `(p+1)%n` => `-~p%n` for -2 bytes

Comment: @Jakque updated

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>106</s> <s>90</s> 42 bytes

```
AtomQ@#&&2^Tr@UnitStep[#-{2,3,5,9}]&@*Log2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b737EkPzfQQVlNzSgupMghNC@zJLgktSBaWbfaSMdYx1THsjZWzUHLJz/d6H9AUWZeCVDGLs1BOVatzrGoKLGyzszkPwA)

Returns the period if it exists, or `False` otherwise.

[Laver Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laver_table) exist iff \$N\$ is a power of 2. The sequence of periods is [A098820](https://oeis.org/A098820) on the OEIS.

Assuming the l3 rank-into-rank cardinal exists, it's been shown that the first \$N\$ for which the period is greater than 16 is at least \$2^{A(9,A(8,A(8,255)))}\ggg2^{31}-1\$, where \$A\$ is the Ackermann function. John Baez has a relatively accessible layman's explanation [here](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2016/05/06/shelves-and-the-infinite/).

Comment: Is there supposed to be a nonprintable U+F4A1 in the middle of your answer?

Comment: @Neil yes: Mathematica uses it for [`\[Function]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html); it's used here to enable recursion on the row-computing function with `#0` (this is the function called on`1-#`). The function on `r` computes `(a*(b+1))=((a*b)*(a+1))` from `r=a*b`.

Comment: Well, its presence seems to completely confuse Firefox 77 for some reason...